# injecting a script into newly opened tab - Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, tabs

I've written an extension to run this snippet of code when a button is clicked, what I need to do is to inject another snipped once run() has opened a new tab.

How would I go about doing this?

```
content_script.js:15 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'onDOMContentLoaded' of undefined
    at injectTheScript (content_script.js:15)
    at run (content_script.js:9)
    at content_script.js:12
```

Please help.

```js
let n = 0;

function run() {
  var links = document.getElementsByClassName('cur_pointer open_in1 new_act_btn col_in center big_link');
  links[n].click();
}

run();

function injectTheScript() {
  chrome.webNavigation.onDOMContentLoaded.addListener(function(details) {
    const tabId = details.tabId;
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {
      code: 'document.getElementsByClassName(\'glyphsSpriteHeart__outline__24__grey_9 Szr5J\')[0].click();'
    });
  });
}

injectTheScript();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only access `chrome.webNavigation` from the background script and not from the content script (you use it from content_script.js).

Comment: How would I go about doing so?

Comment: Start by perusing the overview article in the documentation, then it'll be obvious or you can adapt an existing answer, there should be several on stackoverflow that show how to continue scripting a page after following a link.